# Go To Line in Text Editor

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I tried implementing GoTo ling in a basic editor-type app but isn't always accurate. More often than not, it gets the right line, but it seems that the more lines there are, the more of a chance it will get the line position wrong and go to the wrong line. Not sure why this isn't working. Can someone please help?

```
int position = 0;
int lineCount = ((TextBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Lines.Count();

for (int i = 0; i < LineNumber; i++)
{
     position += ((TextBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Lines[i].Count();
}

((TextBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Focus();
((TextBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).SelectionStart = position;
((TextBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).ScrollToCaret();
LineNumber = 0;
position = 0;
lineCount = 0;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if I have understood you correctly, but a TextBox control has a method called

**TextBoxBase.[GetFirstCharIndexFromLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getfirstcharindexfromline.aspx)**

So if your user wants to go to line 10 (and you have 10 lines) then

```
 int pos = textBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(9);
 textBox1.SelectionStart = pos;
 textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
```

Comment: That's weird, I've never seen that before. But thanks! That works like a charm :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think @Steve has got you covered with TextBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine().

In your original code, though, I think you just needed to account for the carriage return / line feeds at the end of each line (they aren't included when access each line thru the Lines() property).  This example assumes the desired line # is 1 (one) based:

```
        int LineNumber = 6;

        TextBox TB = (TextBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0];

        int position = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= TB.Lines.Length && i < LineNumber; i++)
        {
            position += TB.Lines[i - 1].Length + Environment.NewLine.Length;
        }

        TB.Focus();
        TB.SelectionStart = position;
        TB.SelectionLength = 0;
        TB.ScrollToCaret();
```